# how to use a simple statement to describe repeated format specifiers about function 'sprintf' in C?

Tags: c, string, format-specifiers

Below is my code. I want to make it more efficient.
There are so many format specifiers which are identical.
And there are also similar targets which belong with an array.

My questions are...

1. How can I reduce the number of repeated format specifiers?
2. How can I use a general expression for the targets (double[i])?

Thanks for your help.

```
char * msg = sprintf("%d %lf %lf %lf %lf %lf %lf %lf %lf %lf %lf",
                             intnum,       doublenum[0],  doublenum[1],
                             doublenum[2], doublenum[3],  doublenum[4],
                             doublenum[5], doublenum[6],  doublenum[7],
                             doublenum[8], doublenum[9],  doublenum[10]);
```

Comment: Loop through the array. Also, `sprintf` takes `char *` as first argument.

Comment: can you show me how to do?

Comment: Your pseudo-code is rather too pseudo for comfort; you can't have an array called `double` to index into.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You first need to provide a large enough buffer to write to. The signature of `sprintf` is

```
int sprintf(char *str, const char *format, ...);
```

It returns the amount of characters written to the buffer `str`.

You can capture that value to adjust the pointer into `str` by offsetting by the amount of characters written so far.

Without any error checks and buffer overflow protection, it could look something like this:

```
char msg[BUFSZ];
int msgl = sprintf(msg, "%d", integer);
for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    msgl += sprintf(msg + msgl, " %lf", ds[i]);
}
```

for some large enough `BUFSZ`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I misunderstood the usage of sprinf!!

Comment: in the code "msgl += sprintf(msg + msgl, "%lf ", ds[i]);"
how 'msg+msgl' can be the first parameter of sprintf? I think it is not buffer...
Is 'msg+msgl' new buffer which is sum of previous buffer and ds[i]?

Comment: `msg` is the address to the beginning of the buffer, `msgl` is the offset into said buffer which is adjusted each time content is added. `msg + msgl` then is the address from where on to add the next content, it is addressing relative to the beginning of the buffer `msg`.

Answer (score 2):

A simple [example](https://ideone.com/cwt4io) would be:-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {

    char msg[100]; 
    int x=1, i=0;
    double d[10]; 
    for(i=0; i<10; i++)
        d[i] = i+10.0;
    sprintf(msg, "%d", x); 
    for(i =0; i<10; i++){
        sprintf(msg + strlen(msg), " %lf", d[i]);
    }

    printf("%s\n", msg);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Now I understand it. Thank you!!

Comment: It might be better to avoid the trailing blank by having no space after the `%d` conversion specification, and by having a space before the `%lf` conversion specification instead of after.  This would then be an exact match for the original code.

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is probably code along these lines:

```
double array[10] = { 25.66, 87.51, 38.53, 26.59, 85.54, 47.82, 69.68, 27.79, 21.98, 12.80, };
enum { NUM_ARRAY = sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]) };
char buffer[1024];
int integer = 3141592;

int offset = 0;
int nbytes = snprintf(buffer + offset, sizeof(buffer) - offset, "%d", integer);
if (nbytes < 0) { …report error and stop processing… }
offset += nbytes;
for (int i = 0; i < NUM_ARRAY; i++)
{
    nbytes = snprintf(buffer + offset, sizeof(buffer) - offset, " %lf", array[i]);
    if (nbytes < 0) { …report error and stop processing… }
    offset += nbytes;
}
```

Strictly, the code should check whether `nbytes >= sizeof(buffer) - offset` to ensure there was no truncation.

Whether you regard that as simpler is another matter.  It is, however, vastly more flexible than the original (or has the potential to be more flexible).  If you need to print only 8, or to print some large number of values, then (with the appropriate wrapping in a function) you can handle all variants.  You can play various other tricks, such as ensuring that the output line does not get to be longer than N bytes, inserting a newline and maybe some leading padding.  The sky is the limit.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this simple example code that reads parameters from command line and inserts them into the variable `msg`.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char msg[2000];
    int msgl;
    int x,i,n;
    double d[10];

    //    Load values from command line
    // -----------------------------------------
    if (argc>12 || argc<3) {
        puts("Usage: prgname ni nd1 {nd2,nd3 ..., nd10}\n");
        return 1;
    }

    n=argc-2; // number of double values

    x=atoi(argv[1]);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        d[i]=strtod(argv[i+2],NULL);
    // -------------------------------------------

    // -------------------------------------------
    //     THE ALGORITHM SOLVING THE QUESTION
    // -------------------------------------------
    *msg=0;     // clear msg
    msgl = sprintf(msg,"%d",x);

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        msgl += sprintf(msg + msgl," %lf", d[i]);
    // -------------------------------------------

    puts(msg);
    return 0;
}
```